# how to customize sorting order in django ForeignKey field

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Article(models.Model):
    # usefull staff
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category")  
class Category(models.Model):
     parent = models.ForegnKey('self')
```

I want to display categories selector as a `<select>` field with sorted category tree in it.
It should look like

```
top level category1
  lower level1
  lower level2
    even lower level
    even lower level 2
  lower level3
top level category2
  lower level500
```

Which is the best way to do this? I hoped to use inheritance from ForeignKey class, but it's sophisticated. Maybe the whole question is "How to inherit from multiply inherited classes?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by inheriting ForeignKey class and overriding method

```
def formfield():
   return MyChoiceField(choices = get_category_tree())
```

and `MyChoiceField` is a child of `ChoiceField`, where I've corrected validation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [django-mptt](http://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/) to represent the category tree in the database. Then you can sort by the 'left' value of each category.